# Make element always same height as other element plus 65px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element. We can call that **Element A**. I want **Element A** to have the same `height` as **Element B** with an additional `height` of `65px`. For example if **Element B** has a `height` of `500px` I want **Element A** to have a `height` of `565px`

I am not very good at writing functions. I found one that can make **Element A** the same height as **Element B** but without the additional 60px.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ElementA").css("height", $("#ElementB").height());
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$("#ElementA").height($("#ElementB").height() + 65)`

Comment: Its really that easy? o_0 okay one moment. Thanks!

Comment: That would work, but the problem is that you assuming that **Element A** will always have the highest height, so you will come back and ask the question again differently.

Comment: You can do this purely through CSS. Why use javascript??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the value wanted - 65 in this case

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ElementA").css("height", $("#ElementB").height() + 65);
  
  console.log("A:" + $("#ElementA").height() + "px");
  console.log("B:" + $("#ElementB").height() + "px");
});
```

```css
#ElementA {
  background-color: red;
  width: 10px;
}
#ElementB {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ElementA">A</div>
<div id="ElementB">B</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here my solution

```
$(function(){
  $("#ElementA").css("height", $("#ElementB").height()+65);
});
```

> Here my responsive solution

```
$(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
      $("#ElementA").css("height", $("#ElementB").height()+65);
  }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: You don't have to add `+ 'px'`

Answer (score 1):

You probably best doing it this way.

```
var SameHeights = function (){
    var height = 0;

    $('.allElements').each(function(index, element){
         height = $(element).height() > height ? $(element).height() : height;
    });
    $('.allElements').height(height +65);
}

SameHeights();//call the function here, and re-use it again in the future.
```

Then on your HTML, you will have to add a class (it's better)

```
<div class="allElements">Element A</div>
<div class="allElements">Element B</div>
<div class="allElements">Element C</div>
```

Comment: Element B is inside Element A. So it would look like this
<div class="ElementA">
<div class="ElementB">
</div>
</div>

So if element B's height is always changing. I need element A to always be the same height even if B's height changes but with the additional 65px

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ElementA").height( $("#ElementA").height() + 65 );
});

</script>
```